# Verify that ~(P ↔ Q) ≡ P ↔ ( ~Q) using logical equivalencies (not truth tables)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I have been able to verify this via truth tables but not with logical equivalencies yet. I understand some of the basic principles of logical equivalencies but I cannot seem to get to the end of this problem where one side equals the other.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear: what logical equivalences are you taking as primitive? The laws of boolean algebras perhaps?

Comment: @RobArthan logical equivalencies such as De Morgan's Laws, for example. Others might include distributing negation, etc

Comment: Well if you have enough equivalences to show that a formula is equivalent to a [disjunctive normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form) or a [conjunctive normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form), you are pretty well there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $A\vee(B\wedge C)\equiv (A\vee B)\wedge(A\vee C)$.

On the left hand side, we have

$\neg(P\leftrightarrow Q)\equiv \neg[(P\to Q)\wedge(Q\to P)]\equiv(P\wedge\neg Q)\vee(Q\wedge\neg P)\equiv[(P\wedge\neg Q)\vee Q]\wedge[(P\wedge\neg Q)\vee\neg P]\\\equiv[(P\vee Q)\wedge(\neg Q\vee Q)]\wedge [(P\vee\neg P)\wedge(\neg Q\vee\neg P)]\equiv(P\vee Q)\wedge(\neg Q\vee\neg P)$

Consider the negation of the right hand side and we have

$\neg[(P\to\neg Q)\wedge(\neg Q\to P)]\equiv(P\wedge Q)\vee(\neg Q\wedge\neg P)$

Now we negate it back

$\neg[(P\wedge Q)\vee(\neg Q\wedge\neg P)]\equiv[\neg(P\wedge Q)]\wedge[\neg(\neg Q\wedge\neg P)]\equiv(\neg P\vee\neg Q)\wedge(Q\vee P)$

Hence it gives the result that we are asked to verify.